# how to add content to next div if its exceeding in the first div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to add 5 categories in one div. Currently i am getting all in one div. On adding more categories i want them to display in a next div. Can any please help how can i do this. Here is what i want to achieve [image]

i know i could create col-md-4 * 3 inside col-md-12 but still i would get all categories in first div.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#jobsByindustry"><b>Jobs By Industry</b></a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#jobsByCity"><b>Jobs By city</b></a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#jobsByCompany"><b>Jobs By company</b></a></li>

</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="jobsByindustry" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class=" col-md-12 jobsByCategory">
          <?php if (isset($industries)): ?>
          <?php foreach ($industries as $industry): ?>  
           <a href="<?php echo base_url() ;?>job/jobsbyindustry/<?php echo $industry->industry_id; ?>"><?php echo $industry->industry_name; ?></a><br>
          <?php endforeach ?>
          <?php endif ?>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div id="jobsByCity" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="col-md-12 jobsByCategory">
          <?php if (isset($cities)): ?>
          <?php foreach ($cities as $city):

           ?>  
           <a href="<?php echo base_url() ;?>job/jobsbyindustry/<?php echo $city->city_id; ?>"><?php echo $city->city_name; ?></a><br>
          <?php endforeach ?>
          <?php endif ?>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div id="jobsByCompany" class="tab-pane fade">
      <div class=" col-md-12 jobsByCategory">
            <?php if (isset($companies)): ?>
            <?php foreach ($companies as $company): ?>  
             <a href="<?php echo base_url() ;?>job/jobsbyindustry/<?php echo $company->company_id; ?>"><?php echo $company->company_name; ?></a><br>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            <?php endif ?>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `div` elements are "block-level" elements. That is, they render on the next line down, below any prior content. To get them to display next to each other, you could consider using `float:left` in a CSS rule that targets the `div` elements in question.

Comment: You're using bootstrap it appears, you probably want a `row-fluid` containing three `col-md-4` and not `col-md-12`

Comment: As @Kisaragi said, bootstrap offers a grid system. Each row is 12 wide and 12/3 is a width of 4, so that's where the `col-**-4` came from. The `md` relates to the screen size. Its also the reason why it doesn't work for you atm, `12` takes the full width. Perhaps look at the [`flexbox`](http://www.bootply.com/7UhIWMK808) as well.

Comment: i know i could create col-md-4 * 3 inside col-md-12 but still i would get all categories in first div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery mock-up below. This is based on three columns with the same classname. It cycles through the first column and bumps the list items into the next and subsequent columns accordingly. Steps commented in the fiddle and the css would need to be adapted to suit your situation.

```js
var cats = $('.cols').eq(0).find('li'),
  num = 5;

cats.each(function(i) { // cycle through each li
  if (i >= num) { // start after num counts
    var temp = $(this),
      count = Math.floor(i / num); // work out the multiples
    $('.cols').eq(count).append(temp[0].outerHTML); // add this li to the next eligable column
    temp.remove(); // remove it from the first list
  }
});
```

```css
.cols {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  padding-left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul id="one" class="cols">
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
  <li>some text</li>
</ul>

<ul id="two" class="cols">

</ul>

<ul id="three" class="cols">

</ul>
```